# How can I set the number of threads in the Quartz.NET threadpool?

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I've seen in [this tutorial section](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_10.html) of the Quartz.NET documentation that it should be possible to define the maximum number of threads the Quartz scheduler is going to use. In my special case I want to set this number to 1. But in the API doc I couldn't find a way to access the threadpool instance my scheduler is using and to set any properties on it.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

IScheduler scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
scheduler.Start();

// Setup jobs and triggers and then call scheduler.ScheduleJob...
```

Does somebody know how I can set the number of threads in the pool?

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a bit on the pool you're using and the config file the scheduler is reading. But if you are using the standard `SimpleThreadPool.cs` then the amount of threads can be configured inside the quartz.config file, by default 10 threads are created:

[image]

Comment: In the meantime I found another solution for my purpose: I have only one JobDetail with many parametrized triggers and with setting the ThreadCount to 1 I wanted to make sure that the jobs don't run concurrently. (My Execute method isn't threadsafe.) But the more straightforward-way for this seems to be to implement `IStatefulJob` instead of IJob what I have done now (seems to work as I want). Anyway: You definitely answered my question and it's good to know for the future that there is a config file (which I didn't know until now) and what I can do with it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Bit you are right, implementing the IStatefulJob interface is the best solution to your requirement.

Comment: @Slauma:  The Quartz.Net 2.x way to do that is to decorate your class implementing `IJob` with `[DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute]`

Comment: @EricJ.: Thank you! Good to know for the next project with Quartz.

Comment: @jdecuyper Was "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" wasl "Simpl" a typo?

Comment: I thought so but it is actually correct: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/9a91d01c-9221-f396-cd85-1827bfa5db39.htm

Answer (score 31):

You can do this programmatically with the code below if you don't want to rely on the external `quartz.config` file for whatever reason:

```
    var properties = new NameValueCollection { {"quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1"} };

    var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```

I agree with the comments in the accepted answer though that in this case you probably want to use `[DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute]` on your `IJob` class instead.

Comment: I have done this, but when my IJob class dont have `[DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute]` and I use a sleep in my job,  like [this sample](http://pastebin.com/kzyJYqaj) you see `int a` multiple time before first job ends. that is because when my thread goes to sleep it began to do another scheduled job(**still there is only one thread here**). this was some thing I didnt understand at first and I though may help others, so I leave this comment here :D

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config file add below value under quartz section.

```
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="20" />
```

Value represents the number of threads that are available for concurrent execution of jobs.