# Quartz.Net: Prevent different job types from running concurrently

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

Our system uses Quartz.Net for scheduling and has multiple types of jobs (say: job type A, job type B, job type C). We want to avoid that certain types of jobs run concurrently:

- scenario 1: jobs of type A cannot run concurrently with other jobs of type A.
- scenario 2: jobs of type B cannot run concurrently with jobs of type C. (if this happens then we want the C job to 'wait' until the B job is finished)

I know I can use the `DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute` attribute to implement scenario 1. But I can't figure out how to implement scenario 2 using built-in Quartz.Net functionality.

I could limit the number of worker threads to 1, but that will kill all concurrency, which is undesired. (A-jobs are allowed to run concurrently with B-jobs)

Of course I could program this logic inside the jobs, but preferably I don't want jobs of type B to know about jobs of type C.

Comment: No idea if it would work...but try making a base/abstract class......(public abstract class MyTwoBuddiesNonCurrentBaseJob).......have your two jobs inherit from it........and put your attributes on the abstract class.  I doubt it will work, but worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate scheduler for B and C jobs and configure it to have 1 thread in its pool. From [How can I set the number of threads in the Quartz.NET threadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086122/2833802) SO answer:

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection { {"quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1"} };

var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```